# Get rid of "Show Quoted Text" in Gmail

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

Is there a way to code HTML emails in a way that will NOT show the "show quoted text" and will NOT turn text to purple?
The web app I'm developing sends out a notification each time a user gets a reply on the web app and if the user gets 2 or more replies from the same person everything excpet the date a photo in the email turns to "show quoted text". Even the call-to-action button that's supposed to take the user to the actual conversation.

I know that this question has been answered before but I just can't find it..

Thanks!

Comment: why do you assume the user will be using gmail?

Comment: a lot of them do. I want it to be perfect on all the clients and webmail apps

Answer (score 10):

I think the key for gmail is the subject.  If the subject is the same (from same sender) then it places it in the same 'conversation' and will display "show quoted text".
For me, just modifying the subject slightly causes gmail to treat it as a new conversation thread and hide the body.  So, try adding the time, date or a sequence number to the subject line.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the body of the email, possibly by including a section of the reply, so that gmail won't hide the identical content.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that but it still keeps hiding the call-to-action button which is supposed to take them to the web app. I even tried putting a unique link on it with a timestamp so that on every email it will have a unique link, but it still keeps hiding the button.

Comment: @Nicko Hmmm, maybe try putting the button before the content that's different.